# import redis dump.rdb to cloudfoundry

Tags: node.js, redis, replication, cloud-foundry

I need to import my local dump.rdb to the cloudfoundry redis service that I created.

I opened the tunnel and tried, slaveof localhost 6379 and it returned an error, `(error) ERR unknown command 'slaveof'`

I tried config get command and it returned same unknown error. This is understandable, probably they have disabled config command.

How do I import ? Are there any other ways ?
I searched, but could not find details.

Comment: Can you bundle it in your application? In java land I would put the dump in my war and have it loaded on startup ... just a thought

Comment: By bundling, I hope you mean to include this as part of the node.js app. Is there any way the created redis service will be able to pick the dump.rdb from the app's location ? I have checked that my app at cloudfoundry is able to talk to the redis service. But I dont know how to export the data. I used mongodb also and for mongodb, i used mongorestore through the tunnel to export the local dump. In case of redis, I do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Cloudfoundry uses a client model to communicate with and manipulate the service. In this case, something like, "redis_cli" would be the client. Here are some links I found which describe import/export, and how it might be implemented.

- http://groups.google.com/group/redis-db/browse_thread/thread/3f9cad49a647901a
- https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/288
- https://github.com/delano/redis-dump
- https://github.com/pconstr/rdb-parser